# Replace specific string in file which is not part of the search pattern but in follow up file

Tags: sed, grep, sh

I have a config file like in following example.

```
{
    "view": "pagelogfile",
    "text": "menu_logFile",
    "disabled": false,
    "icon": null,
    "cls": "treelevel2",
    "iconCls": null,
    "users": ["admin", "guest"],
    "expanded": null,
    "leaf": true,
    "data": []
},
{
    "view": "pagemyfeature",
    "text": "menu_myFeature",
    "disabled": false,
    "icon": null,
    "cls": "treelevel2",
    "iconCls": null,
    "users": ["admin", "guest"],
    "expanded": null,
    "leaf": true,
    "data": []
}
```

Depending on a HardwareId certain config options are not available to certain users. For example the view: pagemyfeature is not available for user guest. I would have to remove the user "guest" from the "users array. Since the same array of users appears several time in the config file and i only want to change it in one place to `"users": ["admin"]`, the only searchpattern i have is menu_myFeature to get in the correct config array for that menu. How to do the change in the subseqent line of this array?

This is how i want it to look like

```
{
    "view": "pagelogfile",
    "text": "menu_logFile",
    "disabled": false,
    "icon": null,
    "cls": "treelevel2",
    "iconCls": null,
    "users": ["admin", "guest"],
    "expanded": null,
    "leaf": true,
    "data": []
},
{
    "view": "pagemyfeature",
    "text": "menu_myFeature",
    "disabled": false,
    "icon": null,
    "cls": "treelevel2",
    "iconCls": null,
    "users": ["admin"],
    "expanded": null,
    "leaf": true,
    "data": []
}
```

Grepping for pagemyfeature and also string replacement with sed is not a problem. But how to make sure to replace the string 6 lines later on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to do in `sed`, then try this. There many tools are available to work with `json`.

```
sed '/{/{:loop; N; /pagemyfeature/{:loop2; N; /users/s/,\? *"guest"//g; b loop2;}; /}/b; b loop;}' yourfile
```

More readable format:

```
/{/{
    :loop; 
    N; 
    /pagemyfeature/{
        :loop2; 
        N; 
        /users/s/,\? *"guest"//g; b loop2;
    };

    /}/b;

    b loop;
}
```

Comment: You are right thats it is a json. I am not fixed on sed. What would you suggest to use as json manipulator? Your command however result in with an error unterminated "}" `sed '/{/{:loop; N; /pagemyfeature/{:loop2; N; /users/s/,\? *"guest"//g; b loop2}; /}/b; b loop;}' /var/www/Config/menu.json`

Comment: You can use `jq`. It is like `sed` but especially designed for `json`.

Comment: Thank you for the hint to jq. That works on my host but i need to make it cross compile for my target. I therefore fixed the syntax error in your script above (; missing) and that does the job. Thanks a lot.